# Need to capture the payload of a POST request in the exact format as it's inside HTTP packet

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following form:

```
<form id='myform' action="/result" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And I'm intercepting the submission of it:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener("submit", callback, false);

function callback(e) {
}
```

On submit, I'd like to have the entire payload logged in the exact format as it's going to be put inside HTTP packet, ie:

```
firstname=john&lastname=doe
```

Do I need to iterate over the elements of the form or is there a place, where it's already prepared for sending?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what you need to do and then convert them to a query string format

Comment: Thanks for pointing the right direction. Just found this little piece of code to accomplish this: https://code.google.com/archive/p/form-serialize